# Which filter on filter_input is best for HTML unicode text?

Tags: php, html, unicode

I'm confused by the various filter options on `filter_input`.

I have an INPUT_POST element string which contains HTML entities and unicode characters. This is to be sent as the body of an e-mail message. I wish to retain all the formatting.

What filter/validation options, if any, are best in `filter_input`?

Comment: Omitting the `$filter` parameter (so it defaults to `FILTER_DEFAULT`) should be fine. I can't see how any of the existing filters can accomplish anything useful here.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: That had been my tentative conclusion, but I needed a sanity check before going with it. Many thanks!

Comment: If you're dealing with HTML, perhaps you want an HTML validator / fixer but that's way beyond the ability of the Filter extension. You'll need something based on a DOM parser.